# Why toString() returns different values for the same input in Java?

Tags: java, tostring

I am writing a GUI program which has the JPasswordField to receive text from users. Then I cast this value to string by using this as follow:

```
 char[] pass = txtPass.getPassword(); //where txtPass is the JPasswordField
 System.out.println("Password:");
 ////////////////Check password/////
 for (int i=0; i< pass.length; i++)
    System.out.println(pass[i]);

 System.out.println("String pass"+ pass.toString());
```

However, everything I execute the application, the different of pass.toString() will I receive. I wish them to be the unique one so that I can do more crytpgraphy functions on that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
System.out.println( "String pass: " + new String( pass ) );
```

For the very large exponent use Exponentiation by squaring - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` function on array will *not* return the characters in the array. Try this instead:

```
char[] pass = txtPass.getPassword(); //where txtPass is the JPasswordField
 System.out.println("Password:");
 ////////////////Check password/////
 for (int i=0; i< pass.length; i++)
    System.out.println(pass[i]);

 System.out.println("String pass"+ new String(pass));
```

This will create a new string containing the characters from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the Java SDK API, it states very clearly,

See also [toString of JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#toString%28%29)

public String toString() { return getClass().getName() + "[" + paramString() + "]";}

The toString method returns the toString of the entire Swing component, hence getClass().getName() + paramString(). Whereas the getPassword method returns the actual password that has been typed into the component's password field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

System.out.println("String pass"+ pass.toString());

you can use

```
System.out.println("String pass"+ String.valueOf(pass));
```

Which can fit for your requirement.